# How to draw the spider web

Tags: web-crawler

I have to draw a spider web using data structures. not so big on imagination. Should I use a binary tree or a graph? or other data structures?

Comment: Do you literally mean something like [this](http://zedomax.biz/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/spider.jpg)? How would a binary tree work for that? - a graph would make sense to me. But you've really provided no context...

Comment: this sounds like a homework assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A graph would make the most sense. The particular data structure would likely be a **set**, as the order doesn't really matter. Just start from a center point, and use the set to describe all nodes around the center. Then add the first node to the second, the second to the third, etc. Build the spider web out from the center in that manner.

Comment: yep, i really meant something like that. thanks for the answers :D